# Moved site to new drive, DB won't work with old drive removed

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I have a site in MAMP-PRO for windows (installed on C drive) that I need to move due to a failing drive (F drive). I have moved the site folder to the new drive (N drive) and changed the path for the host in MAMP settings and restarted the servers - everything works fine. When I remove the failing drive, I can not get the site to connect to it's database (regular sites, HTML/PHP only, work fine), but anything database related (like wordpress) just tried to load indefinitely. When I put the failing drive back in - everything works again. I have validated that even with the failing drive in, changes on the new drive are what is reflected in the browser, so I know that the host file and document root changes are working, it's the database connection that seems to be the issue. I have no idea why this would be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Caching plugin in Wordpress was the culprit.